# Why does this code not read the sudoku numbers from csv file and reconstruct it?

Tags: python, csv, recursion, sudoku

This `print_board` is the code to reconstruct the the sudoku.
it works perfectly fine when I use the sudoku numbers from the
board, but it doesn't work from the `sudoku.csv` file. What have I done wrong?

```
""" Sudoku.csv = 
7;8;0;4;0;0;1;2;0
6;0;0;0;7;5;0;0;9
0;0;0;6;0;1;0;7;8
0;0;7;0;4;0;2;6;0
0;0;1;0;5;0;9;3;0
9;0;4;0;6;0;0;0;5
0;7;0;3;0;0;0;1;2
1;2;0;0;0;7;4;0;0
0;4;9;2;0;6;0;0;7 
"""

 #these are the sudoku numbers on the sudoku.csv file 


import csv
with open('sudoko.csv') as f:
    #next(f) 
    board = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    for row in board:
        print(row)

#this is the code to read the sudoku.csv file.

def print_board(bo):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - ")

        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                print(" | ", end="")

            if j == 8:
                print(bo[i][j])
            else:
                print(str(bo[i][j]) + " ", end="")              
print(print_board(row))
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual CSV file or the output, it's kind of difficult to determine what the problem is. Also, I notice you are using a semi-colon as your delimeter when parsing the CSV. Is that intended?

Comment: If the actual CSV file has `board = [[...], ...]` in it, it's not a CSV file.

Comment: I reedited what's written exactly on the sudoku.csv file.

Comment: the board=[[...], ...] was just to check if the "def print_board(bo)" would reconstruct the sudoku numbers properly.  so I know that the problem isn't here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things that don't work.

1. around the `print_board` function there should be no `print` function.
2. don't pass a row to `print_board`, but the whole `board`
3. rather use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to read csv. Then you get the `board` as an array

Here is a working example.

(Since I'm not sure how exactly your CSV looks like, you may have to change the delimiter argument)

```
import numpy as np

# change delimiter depending on your csv file
board = np.loadtxt('sudoko.csv', delimiter=";")

def print_board(bo):

    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - ")
        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
        
            if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                print(" | ", end="")
            if j == 8:
                print(bo[i][j])
            else:
                print(str(bo[i][j]) + " ", end="")


print_board(board)
```

So this is the output:

```
7.0 8.0 0.0  | 4.0 0.0 0.0  | 1.0 2.0 0.0
6.0 0.0 0.0  | 0.0 7.0 5.0  | 0.0 0.0 9.0
0.0 0.0 0.0  | 6.0 0.0 1.0  | 0.0 7.0 8.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
0.0 0.0 7.0  | 0.0 4.0 0.0  | 2.0 6.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0  | 0.0 5.0 0.0  | 9.0 3.0 0.0
9.0 0.0 4.0  | 0.0 6.0 0.0  | 0.0 0.0 5.0
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
0.0 7.0 0.0  | 3.0 0.0 0.0  | 0.0 1.0 2.0
1.0 2.0 0.0  | 0.0 0.0 7.0  | 4.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 4.0 9.0  | 2.0 0.0 6.0  | 0.0 0.0 7.0
```

Comment: However, the downside of numpy is that it outputs `5` as `5.0` (float rather than int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
import csv


with open('sudoko.csv') as f:
    board = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter=';'))


def print_board():
    for row in range(len(board)):
        if row % 3 == 0:
            print('|', ('- '*3 + '| ') * 3)
        for item in range(len(board[row])):
            if item % 3 == 0:
                print('| ', end='')
            print(board[row][item], end=' ')
        print('|')
    print('|', ('- '*3 + '| ') * 3)


print_board()
```

Output:

```
| - - - | - - - | - - - | 
| 7 8 0 | 4 0 0 | 1 2 0 |
| 6 0 0 | 0 7 5 | 0 0 9 |
| 0 0 0 | 6 0 1 | 0 7 8 |
| - - - | - - - | - - - | 
| 0 0 7 | 0 4 0 | 2 6 0 |
| 0 0 1 | 0 5 0 | 9 3 0 |
| 9 0 4 | 0 6 0 | 0 0 5 |
| - - - | - - - | - - - | 
| 0 7 0 | 3 0 0 | 0 1 2 |
| 1 2 0 | 0 0 7 | 4 0 0 |
| 0 4 9 | 2 0 6 | 0 0 7 |
| - - - | - - - | - - - |
```